# Apart from these countries, is there any other one where you can see the auroras and at the same time go to a tropical forest in their territory?

Tags: where-on-earth, countries, geography, auroras, tropical-destinations

Of course, I am including all the overseas territories of these countries: UK, France, The Netherlands, Australia and New Zealand.

In all of the countries I previously mentioned, there is at least one part of the territory containing a tropical rainforest or a jungle (e.g France's French Guiana or Netherland's Saba Island) and in another part of the territory you can see either the aurora borealis or the aurora australis even if it is somewhat rare (e.g again, in the case of France, the Kerguelen Islands and in the case of The Netherlands the northern part of the Frisian Islands).

Are there any more countries in the world with similar characteristics?

From the answers: USA.

Comment: Please do not edit in countries given in the answers as if these had been in from the start. It is OK to make a new line with 'countries from the answers'.

Comment: I would recommend removing the list of countries from the question and creating a community wiki with the full list.

Comment: How about Argentina and Chile?  They both extend into the tropics to the north, and their southernmost points are considerably further south than Australia (Tasmania) or New Zealand (South Island).

Comment: I added the [tag:where-on-earth] tag which is usually what we apply to questions like this.  Since there is a 5-tag limit I had to remove one. I took off [tag:disputed-territories] since it wasn't clear to me how it was related.

Comment: @NateEldredge:  Visibility of aurora is more correlated with [geomagnetic latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_latitude) than with geographic latitude.  This is why aurora are more often seen in Winnipeg than in London (both at 50° N), even independently of issues of light pollution.  And Tasmania is much closer to the south magnetic pole than Tierra del Fuego.

Answer (score 6):

You can frequently see the aurora in Alaska and you can visit the El Yunque National Forest, Puerto Rico both in the United States of America.

Answer (score 4):

[Auroras are sometimes visible in Australia](https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2016-11-08/how-can-you-spot-an-aurora-in-australia/8001204), particularly in Tasmania;  and Queensland has tropical rainforests.

[Under rare circumstances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrington_Event), auroras have been seen within 10 degrees of the Equator.  If we count such events, this would include many other countries with tropical rainforests as well.  The above-linked event caused visible auroras in Mexico, Colombia (!), and presumably much of Central America.  While it's not explicitly mentioned, it wouldn't surprise me if they were visible in Madagascar as well (given its relative proximity to the South Magnetic Pole.)

Comment: The Netherlands which is on the list in the question hardly ever gets any northern lights, and when it is visible it is mostly not very clear. So your list may be as good as that country.

Comment: Forget about seeing both auroras and tropical rainforests, under those circumstances you could see an aurora *in* a rainforest!